# How can I write this SQL query to display assets?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table calls assets with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE assets
(
   id int,
   location_id int,
   updated_at timestamp
)
```

An asset could be assigned to different locations by time, but only one location at a time, this table track all the assets and all the location changes. such as

```
(1,1,2022-08-01)
(1,2,2022-09-01)
(1,3,2022-10-01)
(2,1,2022-01-01)
(3,2,2022-10-05)
(4,1,2022-01-01)
(4,2,2022-02-01)
```

I need a query for the following results: return assets which has newly deployed within a month or relocated within a month. For the above data set, it should return:

(1)--Asset 1 relocated within a month
(3)--Asset newly deployed within a month.

How can I write this query?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail or perhaps a query you've started with?  For example, you indicate Asset 1 has been relocated within a month, but the dates you have (assuming YYYY-MM-DD) are in two different months.  You might also consider formatting your data set response to make it clearer as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Asset 1, in location 1 since 2022-08-01, then Asset1, relocated to 1 since 2022-09-01, then relocated to 3 since 2022-10-01. And the last relocated is happened on 2022-10-01, which is within a month, so that asset shold be returned. Is that make sense?

Comment: not exactly.  All the dates you provided for asset 1, occur in August, then September, then October.  Can you define what "within a month" means in this example?

Comment: Ha, I see what you talking about. Sorry for the confusion. So today is 2022-10-13, within a month means all updated happened after 2022-09-13. asset 1 for instance, because the last update happened on 2022-10-01, so asset 1 should be returned.

Comment: Recommend you look at [date/time functions in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).  Specifically you could do `SELECT * FROM assets WHERE age(updated_at) <= interval '1 month'`

Comment: You might want to have an id that is just a number that increase and use something like asset_id for what you currently have as id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should get you started down a path at least but I pulled all the rows that occurred in the last month and then look to see their last update time was.  You can adjust message/formatting as needed.

You can also look at Postgres window functions, like lag or lead if you need to have a deeper look into the past history.

```
select id, location_id, updated_at, 
(select max(updated_at) from assets a2 where a2.id = a.id and a2.updated_at < a.updated_at) as last_update_at
from assets a
where a.updated_at between current_timestamp - interval '1 month' and current_timestamp;
```

[image]